# Android listview Items and menu

Tags: android, android-listview, android-menu

In my android application I have a listview that displaying user contacts. I need to implement a option menu that has a menu item Name "Add to favourites" which will add the selected contact from the listview to favourites list.

I am strugling of how to track the selected item from the listview to add to favourite list. Also The "Add to favourites" menu item should only display only when we press the menu button and if an Item in the listview have selected. Because there exists other buttons and all in the page and only it should display to add a contact to favourites list.

Comment: use `Context Menu` for this. Refer this doc: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: Hi Vineet Shukla, The thing is to fullfill the requirement I have to any how do it using Option Menu.. Where I am Struggling for the whole day now is to find a way of how to track the which listview item had selected to add to favourites list by menu item. Thanks

Comment: I tried with initializing a global variable like this, boolean focusOnList = false; and in onFocusChangeListener make it true when hasFocus(focusOnList = true) and when no focus, focusOnList = false. Anyway when page loads automatically focusOnList value is getting true but no item in listview selected

Comment: you can put focus listener over list and on focus save the required value in your local variable and thru options menu you can add it to your favourite list..

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
  try {
    info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
  }   
  catch (ClassCastException e) { }

  // get the item for which the menu is shown
  Object item = getListAdapter().getItem(info.position);
}
```

Comment: Hi BlackRider, I have to use an option menu to implement this.

Comment: oh, sorry, i misunderstood the question.